# Unity, Applovin MAX & UniWebView: low FPS in webview

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, webview, applovin, uniwebview

Our setup:

- Unity 2020.3.47
- UniWebView 5.3.0
- Applovin MAX (Unity 5.10.1 / Android 11.10.1)
- Android build

We have a browser game running on Phaser in UniWebView. We try to integrate Applovin MAX but run into an issue. The problem is that FPS drops dramatically when running HTML canvas scenes after Applovin initialization. Actually, there are 2 scenarios (we ran tests with only one mediation network enabled at a time):

Scenario 1: The game runs smoothly until the first ad is watched (networks: Applovin, Facebook, Mintegral)

Scenario 2: The game starts lagging after Applovin is initialized, even if no ad is loaded (networks: AdMob, Unity Ads, Ironsource)

Our guess was that some other webpage is consuming CPU on the same thread as our game, because webview inspector showed some other pages running in the same webview after AdMob initialization:

[image: Chrome inspect tool when the game is ran with AdMob enabled]

But in the case with only Applovin enabled (no other networks), inspector shows only our webpage, and it's still lagging:

[image: Chrome inspect tool when the game is ran with only Applovin enabled]

We tried running performance profiler in the Chrome inspect tool, and that's what it shows when the game is lagging:

[image: Chrome profiler when FPS is low]

And that's what it shows when the game runs smoothly:

[image: Chrome profiler when FPS is normal]

There's also a trace tool in the inspector and it shows dropped frames:

[image: Chrome tracer tool when FPS is low]

The Unity profiler doesn't show any difference whether the game is lagging or runs smoothly.

So we are trying to find answers to these questions:

1. Is there a way or a tool to detect what's consuming the CPU?
2. Is there a workaround to stop Applovin from affecting webview performance?

UPD: A possible workaround for us is switching Phaser rendering mode from Canvas to WebGL. It seems to improve performace, but it's related to some issues since we use old Phaser 2.6.2.